# Best settings to reduce cycles memory consumption

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, memory-management

I'm trying to render a very complex scene with blender and it seems to be using too much memory. I've already tried using tile size as a multiple of total resolution and spatial bvh splits.

Can anyone recommend any settings that can reduce memory consumption of the scene?
Note, I'm talking about a still render.

Comment: GPU or CPU? (see the wiki on [GPU rendering](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/GPU_Rendering#CUDA_Error:_Out_of_memory))

Comment: My GPU and CPU do not have much difference in their render time.So,help for any of them will do.

Comment: Not sure this is such a useful question to ask, AFAIK there are no knobs to tweak to give better memory performance. A more useful question could be to give the use case that causes excessive memory use, then ask for ways to resolve.

Comment: @YashAggarwal memory wise, CPU and GPU behave a bit differently, the GPU has it's own memory (and usually has less than the system memory used by the CPU)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some hints for better memory usage.
Though with only general info its hard to give a good answer.

- Avoid floating point textures where possible - typically EXR, HDR.
  *(includes 16bit PNG, TIFF, JPEG2000 which are converted to floating-point), these use 4x memory.*
- Avoid displaying textured objects in the viewport (OpenGL-GLSL), this will load textures into memory which is **not** shared with Cycles - so the textures get loaded twice.
- Use instanced objects where possible.
- Take care using subsurf, curve-render subdivision levels.

The only other suggestions would be to reduce memory use from the rest of Blender.

- Render in background mode. or...
- Reduce undo steps (undo can use a lot of ram), you could even dissable undo.

There may not be a whole lot you can do, if you already checked that you don't have excessively high geometry or high-resolution textures, perhaps you just have to render less complex scenes or buy more ram.

Comment: Is the [power of 2 texture trick](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Types/Image#About_Image_Based_Texturing) relevant for cycles?

Comment: Thanks,I reduced the subsurf of most of the objects and it finally rendered.

@gandalf3 - I've not found textures with power of 2 having much effect in cycles with my other projects,but i'm not sure

Comment: A clever way to use memory is splitting the scene in layers as explained here http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/how-to-render-a-complex-scene-without-crashing/

Comment: Can the jpeg texture also affect the rendering quality? I face this weird texture issue (https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqxXg.png) when rendering on GPU vs CPU machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are rendering Fur, pay close attention to the Cycles Hair Settings-Root.  the difference between 0.10 and 0.20 made render possible with enough fur and children to look good.